# PayPal - Native Checkout SDK(iOS)-invalid client_id or redirect_uri

Tags: ios, swift, paypal

[image]

I'm using the new Native Checkout PayPal SDK for iOS and I've been following every step in the documentation but getting -invalid client_id or redirect_uri.

```
        let config = CheckoutConfig(
        clientID: "clientID",
        returnUrl: "returnUrl://paypalpay",
        environment: .sandbox
    )
    
    Checkout.set(config: config)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your client_id is true than you need to set returnUrl to your SDK init and to PayPal dashboard. For the returnUrl you can use deeplink with your url scheme on my case "xxx//:paypalpay".

```
        let config = CheckoutConfig(clientID: "XXX", returnUrl: "XXX://paypalpay", environment: environment)
    Checkout.set(config: config)
```